# Connect Azure Blob Storage to Grafana

Tags: excel, azure, azure-blob-storage, grafana, grafana-loki

I hope you are well. I  have uploaded the excel file into my azure container commonly known as Azure Blob Storage. Let me know if their is an open source connector out there.
I will try to catch up with you thanks a lot.

Kind Regards,
Osama

I tried to use azure plugins available on the grafana website But they are  asking for tenant details and so on. So, I could not find the details from the azure portal. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you tried using "Azure Data Explorer" data source in Grafana. This is used to connect to Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) cluster. This is not the same as Azure Storage Accounts where blobs are stored.

As the data source here is an excel sheet which is stored as a blob in Azure Storage Container, you could convert it to csv and use plugins like [Infinity](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/yesoreyeram-infinity-datasource/), [Csv](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-csv-datasource/) which can visualize data from csv. In this case, the URL supplied to graphana data-source would be the URL of csv in Azure storage container.